# Apache Commons CLI : Getting array of string values for an option

Tags: java, apache, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

got a problem with Commons CLI 1.4
I need to parse unlimited values string Option like exmpl :

**-fe .magnet .torrent**  (paramenter value starts with dot)

i create this `Option` via `Option.builder()`

```
Option fe = Option.builder().argName("fe").desc("bla bla").hasArgs().longOpt("fileextensions").build();
```

and next i add this to my `Options` object

```
options.addOption(fe);
```

then i parse this,i get a Exception

`org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -fe`

how to make right way to parse two or more this parameters,separate via space-symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was easy, when we use a `Option.builder()`, we need to pass him a arg with **'opt'** , my code works on :

`Option.builder("fe").desc("blabla").hasArgs().longOpt("fileextensions").build();`